# Terraform remote-exec: "error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged"

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I'm trying to run some inline remote-exec commands on a DigitalOcean droplet I provision with Terraform.

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline=[
      "whoami",
      "sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.18/stable"
    ]
  }
```

The first command returns "root" correctly but after that I get:

```
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec): Connecting to remote host via SSH...
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec):   Host: 111.11.11.111
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec):   User: root
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec):   Password: false
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec):   Private key: true
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec):   Certificate: false
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec):   SSH Agent: true
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec):   Checking Host Key: false
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec): Connected!
digitalocean_droplet.example: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec): root
digitalocean_droplet.example (remote-exec): error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged
```

Any advice? I'm new to Terraform, maybe missed something fundamental in docs.

Comment: Sounds like snapd isn't ready yet. Have you tried waiting for it with `snap wait system seed.loaded` as mentioned in https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cant-install-or-refresh-snaps-on-arch-linux/8690/35 ?

Comment: Also if you are connecting as root then you don't need the `sudo`.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR That fixed this error, thanks. But now I get `(remote-exec): /tmp/tf.sh: 3: microk8s: not found` which I guess is a separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the error only occurs when I try to install a snap application immediately after installing the snap itself. After running the command below the "snap install" worked fine.

```
sudo snap wait system seed.loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

you should disable SELinux on that server:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```